# Где посмотреть реализацию стандартной библиотеки?

Tags: c++

Для углубления в программирование решил заняться изучением/переписыванием stl. Подскажите где я могу посмотреть ее реализацию? Описание в хедерах - не плохо, но этого недостаточно.

Comment: Ну вообще-то и большая часть реализации тоже в хедерах. Место нахождения реализации следует определять для конкретных вариантов бибилиотек. Если речь идет о VS, то исходники библиотеки лежат в папке `<toolkit_name>/crt/src`

Comment: А чего это вдруг недостаточно? STL - это библиотека шаблонов (название как бы намекает), она в заголовочных файлах и находится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, речь идёт не об оригинальной [STL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2), написанной Александром Степановым, а о стандартной библиотеке C++. У неё реализаций много: почти каждый компилятор имеет свою, и не у всех открыты исходники. Однако, есть открытые. Например, GCC использует libstdc++, исходники которой доступны для просмотра онлайн [здесь](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3) (это зеркало для git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git). У clang (LLVM) есть libc++, исходники которой доступны [здесь](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/master/libcxx/).

Comment: Да, я действительно имел ввиду стандартные библиотеки c/c++. Спасибо.

Comment: @Morphey дружеский совет: не пытайтесь смотреть реализацию libstdc++, сразу смотрите libc++, сбережёте время и нервы.